# How to use PHP Curl from android WebView app?

Tags: java, php, android, localhost

When I enable XAMPP i can send Curl request to any website from local .php file. Is it possible to simulate localhost and do same on ANDROID html WebView app?

Can i access other website's data if i built in localhost inside webview app and run .php file from that app like XAMPP localhost does

Is there any way to simulate localhost on android app and use .php file to (.php file must be wrapped into android app but not on server) access other website without CORS issue

Main reasons i am asking here:

1. I can't find answer on the google.
2. I don't want bay hosting and upload .php file to access curl possibilities, I just need .php file to send curl request from WebView app using simulated localhost inside

Can i enable/disable localhost on WebView app?

Comment: To start with one preconception: every device is its own localhost. Your pc, my pc, my laptop, your laptop, my other pc, my Android device, your Android device. All Android devices are there own localhost. Now please rewrite your post to make clear which localhost you mean.

Comment: @blackapps localhost means localhost on device where app is installed.

Comment: I asked you to rewrite your post. Not to add a comment. Write a post that everybody can follow and understand